# SSRS - Grouping - folder hierarchy

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2008

I have following table having data as followed,
Table name: tblFolder

```
FolderId | FolderName | ParentFolderId
1        | A          | Null
2        | B          | 1
3        | C          | 2
4        | D          | Null
5        | E          | 4
```

ParentFolderId is having FolderId as a parent folder for ex. folder A is parent of folder B

I want to show above data is SSRS report in following format.

```
-A
 -B
  -C
-D
 -E
```

So my question is to show report in above format what should be the my sql query or what approach should I follow?
I don't want to user recursive hierarchy I want to do it by using column grouping

Comment: your task is calculate Identation, which is count of leading spaces. Afraid that the best way - is recursive calculating

Comment: Check SSRS hierarchy reports https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/create-a-recursive-hierarchy-group-report-builder-and-ssrs

Answer (score 0):

We might require to use CTE and do some replace work with string as below:

```
;With cte as 
(
    Select *, convert(varchar(10), Concat('-',FolderName)) as Levl from #Folder where ParentFolderId is null

    Union all

    Select f.Folderid, f.FolderName, f.ParentFolderId, convert(varchar(10),concat(' ',Replace(c.Levl, right(c.levl,len(f.folderName)),f.folderName))) as Levl from cte c inner join #Folder f
        on c.Folderid = f.ParentFolderId
)
select Levl from cte
order by Folderid
```

Output as below:

```
    +------+
    | Levl |
    +------+
    | -A   |
    |  -B  |
    |   -C |
    | -D   |
    |  -E  |
    +------+
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is a standard recursive cte, but we add a generated sequence to ensure the proper presentation order/nesting

**-- Adjusted for 2008 --**

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([FolderId] varchar(50),[FolderName] varchar(50),[ParentFolderId] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1,'A',NULL)
,(2,'B',1)
,(3,'C',2)
,(4,'D',NULL)
,(5,'E',4)

Declare @Top    int         = null      --<<  Sets top of Hier Try 2 
Declare @Nest   varchar(25) = '|-----'  --<<  Optional: Added for readability

;with cteP as (
      Select Seq  = cast(10000+Row_Number() over (Order by FolderName) as varchar(500))
            ,FolderId
            ,ParentFolderId 
            ,Lvl=1
            ,FolderName 
      From   @YourTable 
      Where  IsNull(@Top,-1) = case when @Top is null then isnull(ParentFolderId ,-1) else FolderId end
      Union  All
      Select Seq  = cast(p.Seq+'.'+cast(10000+Row_Number() over (Order by r.FolderName) as varchar(25) )  as varchar(500))
            ,r.FolderId
            ,r.ParentFolderId 
            ,p.Lvl+1
            ,r.FolderName 
      From   @YourTable r
      Join   cteP p on r.ParentFolderId  = p.FolderId)
Select A.FolderId
      ,A.ParentFolderId 
      ,A.Lvl
      ,FolderName = Replicate(@Nest,A.Lvl-1) + A.FolderName
 From cteP A
 Order By Seq
```

**Returns**

```
FolderId    ParentFolderId  Lvl  FolderName
1           NULL            1    A
2           1               2    |-----B
3           2               3    |-----|-----C
4           NULL            1    D
5           4               2    |-----E
```

Comment: Thanks for replying.
In SSRS I exactly want to show as FolderName format so on which column we can set row groping?